# Whether the cmake stage can generate source files？

Tags: cmake

I have such a requirement. I want to modify my source file according to the configuration file in the cmake stage. Is there a good way?

Answer (score 0):

[configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) command is your friend.

First you create a template file filled with strings line `${MY_VAR}` (called `foo.ext.in` by convention) and then pass into as the argument of `configure_file`. During configuration step, CMake will generate `foo.ext` file from your template, substituting any `${VARS}` with corresponding values from CMake code scope.